# Windows Service Context like Website HttpContext

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-services

I am currently working on a Windows Service that does a database call and does some work and then waits for several seconds to run again.  I have to connect to a database during the work and I would like to keep the database connection somewhere that I know will be cleaned up when the object is done.

I was thinking of using something like HttpContext but obviously Windows Services do not have anything like that.  What is the best way to make sure my connections are disposed properly after each call?

Comment: IMHO: Normally i just Close the connection, and don't worry about disposing of the object. The CLR does connection pooling behind the scenes and will decide how and when to dispose and/or reuse connections that you have dropped all references to. Only worry about it if you are having performance troubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always fallback to **static** properties possible. So you can keep it in a static variable on a class.

```
public class ServiceContext
{
    public static DbConnection Connection {get; set;}
}
```

However, this is **not good practice**. It seems that you need to:

1. Encapsulate the operation in a class. This will run and then close the connection.
2. Use Async paradigm to run the operation. You will ensure that you are not bugging the main  operations of the service while database call is being made.

Best is to use TPL: `Task<T>`.